# Calling RAND() From a function in mysql returns the same value:

Tags: mysql, random

As a query, this returns different values each execution:

```
SELECT FLOOR(200000000000 + (RAND() * 100000000000))
```

Writing a function which does the same (To be called from a stored procedure):

```
DROP FUNCTION if exists setRandomNumber//
CREATE FUNCTION setRandomNumber()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

 DECLARE rand INT DEFAULT 0;

 SELECT FLOOR(200000000000 + (RAND() * 100000000000)) INTO rand;

RETURN rand;
END//
```

Always yields the same number:

```
SELECT setRandomNumber();
```

yields:

setRandomNumber()
2147483647

setRandomNumber()
2147483647

setRandomNumber()
2147483647

setRandomNumber()
2147483647

And so on.

Is this a bug? How can I iteratively set more than one random number in a function or stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're maxing out the limit of a integer - 200000000000 is too large

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it. Just figured that out . . .  doh! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use for your case BIGINT instead of INT for returning value